# Google Maps Android API authentication issue

Tags: android, authentication, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm trying to use Google Maps on Android, but I'm getting these messages:

`I/Google Maps Android API(21300): Failed to contact Google servers. Another attempt will be made when connectivity is established.`

`E/Google Maps Android API(21300): Failed to load map. Error contacting Google servers. This is probably an authentication issue (but could be due to network errors).`

This is my Manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.maps"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.example.maps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.maps.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.example.maps.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.maps.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyAXea0N99Lndg-fFN7y9HupDHvorl3QbDI" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

I have created access key in Google APIs console(app is signed with a debug key, so I took SHA1 fingerprint from Eclipse Preferences->Android->Build->SHA1 fingerprint):
[image: picture]
and enabled only `Google Maps Android API v2` in `Services`:
[image: picture]

I have no idea what is wrong. Can someone suggest me a solution?

Comment: you may want to remove your api key

Comment: Is it possible to use it without signing apk with same keystroke? I will make a new key after I find a solution.

Comment: have you re-installed or forced closed the app after adding the key?